# Array declaration and size initialization (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, header, size, declaration

I'm not exactly sure how to pose this question so I'll start with some example code:

```
//header file
class A
{
public:
    A();
private:
    int x;
    std::string arr[x];
}

//cpp file

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
     /*code to get the value of x from a cmd call*/
    }
}
```

Is this code valid? More specifically, can I have my string array in my header file be of size x, even though x is not specifically given a value until an A object has been created?

If this doesn't work, is my only other option to use a dynamically allocated array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not valid. You should use a vector instead.

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
private:
    int x;
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
};

A::A () : x(command_gets_x()), arr(x) {}
```

Since `arr` is being initialized by the value of `x`, the constructor only works when `x` precedes `arr` in `A` (as it is in your definition). However, if the only purpose of `x` is to track the size of the array, it is not necessary, since a `vector` has the `size()` method.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : arr(command_gets_x()) {}
    int x () const { return arr.size(); }
    //...
private:
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps a note that this only works when `x` is declared before `arr` in the class? Or that we don't need `x` when we have `arr.size()`.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose this is another question all together, but if I was to make this vector a 2-D array with a predetermined width of 6, would the proper initialization be:


std::vector<vector<std::string>> arr(command_get_x(),vector<int>(6,0));

Comment: @user1553248: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > arr(command_get_x(),std::vector<std::string>(6));`

Comment: @user1553248: For bidimensional arrays, I would suggest that you write an [adapter class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-subscript-op.html) that internally stores a single `std::vector<>` and provide accessors that map the 2 coordinates into that linear space. The advantages are multiple, from the fact that it is easier to avoid mistakenly creating jagged arrays, to lesser allocations (better memory footprint, better locality)...

Answer (score 3):

It's not valid. Array sizes must be constant expressions. Yes, you'll have to use dynamic allocation, though not necessarily directly. You can just use std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, for one C++ doesn't have variable length arrays, and further, the array size must be a compile time constant.

You can in the constructor allocate an array with `new`, or, better use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't initialize arrays with non-const expressions.  This will work, and is close to your original intent:

```
class A
{
   ...
   const int x = 3;
   std::string arr[x];
};
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
int A::x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that on my mac, in x-code I could do the following

```
int x = foo() // get some value for x at runtime
int array[ x ];
```

but that is seriously uncool!! I just read yesterday that some compilers allow dynamic allocation on the stack, but I would recommend that you stay well clear of that.

If the value of x is not known until runtime, then you cannot allocate an array of size x until runtime. Think about what the compiler does: can an array of size x be allocated if we don't know how big x is? The only remaining option is to allocate at run-time (aka dynamically allocate).

Comment: That seems pretty crazy.  Is it compliant with the standard?